# Processing results from geocoding and storing them in a Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, loops, google-maps, geocoding

I am sending an API request to Google Maps using the geopy library to get an area name for each address in my pandas dataframe and then attempting to store it in its own column.

```
import geopy
import numpy as np

from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3

def get_area(address):
    geolocator = GoogleV3(api_key=api_key, domain='maps.googleapis.com', scheme=None, client_id=None, 
                      secret_key=None, 
                     user_agent=None )
    geocode = RateLimiter(geolocator.geocode, min_delay_seconds=1)
    data = geocode((address), timeout=None)
    #print(data.raw)
    area = []
    for item in data.raw['address_components']:

        if data.raw is None:
            area.append(None)
            continue


        found = False
        typs = set(item['types'])
        if typs == set(['neighborhood', 'political']): 
            print(item['long_name'])
            area.append(item['long_name'])
            found = True
            break

        if not found:
            area.append(None)

    return area

df_test['Area'] = df_test[['L_Address']].apply(lambda row: get_area(row['L_Address']), axis=1)
```

Just for clarity, this is what the raw response from Google Maps looks like:

```
{'address_components': [{'long_name': '7155', 'short_name': '7155', 'types': ['street_number']}, {'long_name': 'Hall Road', 'short_name': 'Hall Rd', 'types': ['route']}, {'long_name': 'Newton', 'short_name': 'Newton', 'types': ['neighborhood', 'political']}, 'location_type': 'ROOFTOP', 'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 49.1335569802915, 'lng': -122.8458199197085}, 'southwest': {'lat': 49.1308590197085, 'lng': -122.8485178802915}}}
```

This is the response I am getting for the code above:

```
0           [None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
1           [None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
2           [None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
3                      [None, None, South Westminster]
4                                [None, None, Whalley]
5           [None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
6           [None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
7                                 [None, None, Newton]
8                                [None, None, Whalley]
9           [None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
10          [None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

So here I know I messed up somewhere in my loop because I only need one single area name for each row. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue. If you just need one value per row then, change your loop to look like this:

```py
    for item in data.raw['address_components']:

        if data.raw is None:
            area.append(None)
            break


        found = False
        typs = set(item['types'])
        if typs == set(['neighborhood', 'political']): 
            print(item['long_name'])
            area.append(item['long_name'])
            found = True
            break

        if not found:
            area.append(None)
            break
```

Comment: returns all None